# The problem with "would"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is the context :

Jim has the daughter who wants her father to buy the dog.
Jim tells the daughter that " our landlord is afraid of dogs".
But the daughter answer that "Charlie's just a little dog".

My question is how to understand the below Jim's answer :

That's the worst kind. What's more, with our luck, the dog would bite him and he would make us move out.

Comment: Which part do you need help with?

Comment: The first sentence refers to 'little dog': "A little dog is the worst kind of dog." The second is a conditional:  "Our luck is such that [if we got the dog] the dog would bite the landlord, and the landlord would make us move."

Comment: Actually, it refers to the both sentences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Would* is expressing the conditional mood here.

> With our luck, the dog would bite him and he would make us move out.

The sentence is saying there's a possibility the dog might bite him, and that he would make them move out.

We can't say *will bite*/*will make us move out* because the speaker/writer believes this is a possible outcome, not a definite outcome.